# Qual o nome desse 'efeito' de selecionar objetos e como fazer em JS puro?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como é o nome desse 'efeito' ('-') que serve para selecionar pastas e arquivos no Windows Explorer.

[image: ssssssssss]

---

E se possível queria saber como fazer isso com JavaScript puro.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Passo 1 - Criando o "retângulo selecionador"

A principal característica desse "efeito" é ter um retângulo criado durante o processo de seleção para demarcar a área que está sendo selecionada. Ele tem um vértice no ponto inicial do clique e o outro que acompanha o cursor, e só é visível enquanto segurando o mouse.

Primeiro criamos uma `<div>` invisível e aplicamos algum CSS para dar o visual desejado:

```html
<div id="selection"></div>
```

```css
#selection {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: lightblue;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Tendo isso vamos nos basear nos eventos `onmousedown`, `onmousemove` e `onmouseup` para criar o comportamento. Segue o código:

```js
(function() {
    var beginX, beginY; // a posição do vértice fixo
    var active; // se a seleção está ativa (visível)
    var selection = document.getElementById("selection"); // o elemento

    window.onmousedown = function (e) {
        beginX = e.clientX;
        beginY = e.clientY;
        active = true;
        selection.style.display = "block"; // deixar a div visível
        window.onmousemove(e); // forçar a atualização de posição (função abaixo)
    };

    window.onmousemove = function (e) {
        if (active) {
            // cx,cy = a posição do segundo vértice
            var cx = e.clientX;
            var cy = e.clientY;

            // x,y,w,h = o retângulo entre os vértices
            var x = Math.min(beginX, cx);
            var y = Math.min(beginY, cy);
            var w = Math.abs(beginX - cx);
            var h = Math.abs(beginY - cy);

            // aplicar a posição e o tamanho
            selection.style.left = x+"px";
            selection.style.top = y+"px";
            selection.style.width = w+"px";
            selection.style.height = h+"px";
        }
    };

    window.onmouseup = function (e) {
        active = false; // desligar
        selection.style.display = "none"; // e ocultar
    };
})();
```

Para manter o cursor estável como uma seta e evitar que fique mudando para outros durante a seleção (experimente clicar e arrastar em uma página vazia, ele muda), usarei esse CSS. Não é exatamente bonito, mas funciona:

```css
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Aqui o resultado até agora: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6BHQ3/5/).

### Passo 2 - Criando itens selecionáveis

Agora temos um retângulo como desejável. Mas ele não tem função alguma por enquanto. Falta criar coisas selecionáveis. Vamos criar algumas:

```html
<div class="selectable">A</div>
<div class="selectable">B</div>
<div class="selectable">C</div>
<div class="selectable">D</div>
<div class="selectable">E</div>
<div class="selectable">F</div>
<div class="selectable">G</div>
<div class="selectable">H</div>
```

```css
.selectable {
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Isso deve criar um monte de quadradinhos com letras. Nossos alvos. Para fazer a seleção interagir com eles basta que toda a vez que o mouse for movido se verifique a quais itens o retângulo de seleção se sobrepõe. Tudo que precisa ser feito é uma checagem de colisão de retângulos dentro de um loop. Para se obter o retângulo de cada item usa-se a função `getBoundingClientRect()`. No fim da função `onmousemove`:

```js
// procurar elementos selecionados
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("selectable");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    var rect = list[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.bottom > y && rect.top < y+h && rect.right > x && rect.left < x+w) {
        list[i].classList.add("mark");
    }
    else {
        list[i].classList.remove("mark");
    }
}
```

E no `onmouseup` desmarcar o que ficou marcado:

```js
// desmarcar tudo.
// aqui você pode fazer algo diferente manter marcado
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("selectable");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
     list[i].classList.remove("mark");
}
```

Esse é o ponto em que você pode fazer algo com a seleção, como manter os itens marcados por exemplo.

É claro, a classe `.mark` para que possamos ver o efeito:

```css
.selectable.mark {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Mais uma vez: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7y3A/5/).

### Passo 3 - Limitando um contêiner

Agora talvez não queiramos que a página inteira seja uma área de seleção, mas limitar tudo isso a um único elemento. Vamos definir um contêiner:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="selection"></div>

    <div class="selectable">A</div>
    <div class="selectable">B</div>
    <div class="selectable">C</div>
    <div class="selectable">D</div>
    <div class="selectable">E</div>
    <div class="selectable">F</div>
    <div class="selectable">G</div>
    <div class="selectable">H</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Para isso funcionar vamos usar novamente o `getBoundingClientRect()` e pegar um retângulo limite.

```js
var limit = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();
```

Em primeiro lugar, adicionar ao começo da `onmousedown` para que nada aconteça se o clique foi fora do limite:

```js
// se o clique foi fora do limite, não continuar
if (e.clientX > limit.right || e.clientX < limit.left ||
    e.clientY > limit.bottom || e.clientY < limit.top) {
    return;
}
```

Como última modificação, fazer com que o segundo vértice da seleção (aquele que é móvel e segue o cursor) nunca deixe o limite. No `onmousemove`:

```js
var cx = Math.max(Math.min(e.clientX, limit.right), limit.left);
var cy = Math.max(Math.min(e.clientY, limit.bottom), limit.top);
```

O resultado até aqui: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LT6pR/3/).

### Passo 4 - O maligno scroll

O problema até aqui é que você por itens suficientes para causar um overflow e crie scroll, ele não será levado em conta e a seleção acontecerá na posição errada.

Isso acontece por que a posição do mouse é retornada em relação à tela e não ao ponto 0,0 da página. Também o `getBoundingClientRect()` se refere à tela. Sendo assim não precisamos mexer na checagem do `onmousedown`, mas precisamos setar valores corretos no `beginX/Y`. Então:

```js
beginX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
beginY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
```

Já no `onmousemove` temos algumas mudanças a fazer. Primeiro criar variáveis para a posição real do mouse, referente ao `body` e não à tela:

```js
var sx = document.body.scrollLeft;
var sy = document.body.scrollTop;

var mx = e.clientX + sx;
var my = e.clientY + sy;
```

E usar essas variáveis no calculo do vértice:

```js
var cx = Math.max(Math.min(mx, limit.right), limit.left);
var cy = Math.max(Math.min(my, limit.bottom), limit.top);
```

Agora `x,y,w,h` estarão corretos, mas a comparação que checa quais itens estão selecionados vai falhar pois `getBoundingClientRect()` ainda se refere à tela. Basta corrigir as medidas na condicional:

```
var rect = list[i].getBoundingClientRect();
if (rect.bottom+sy > y && rect.top+sy < y+h && rect.right+sx > x && rect.left+sx < x+w) {
    list[i].classList.add("mark");
}
else {
    list[i].classList.remove("mark");
}
```

O resultado final: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnN55/3/).

Comment: =O o/ se fosse possível eu queria que o 'selection' selecionasse divs, como mostra na imagem lá, se for possível :D

Comment: Agora você tem o retangulo da seleção e o retuangulo de cada div. Basta calcular uma colisão de retangulos dentro do `onmousemove` para cada div "selecionável". A ideia base é essa.

Comment: ah certo, vlw o/

Comment: Teria como você atualizar o seu exemplo para selecionar a divs? rsrsrs não consegui fazer =/

Comment: @IagoBruno adicionei um exemplo para isso também

Comment: **Obrigado @GuilhermeBernal \Õ/**

Comment: Só uma coisa, eu quero que dê para somente selecionar elementos dentro de uma tag, caso eu começar a selecionar fora da tag, não vai funcionar, tentei fazer isso mas não deu muito certo, usei o método e.target para verificar, mas ele checa o elemento clicado ou seja se eu clicar em algum elemento dentro da tag ele vai mandar a tag clicada não a tag que eu quero '-' acho que você entendeu kkkkkkk

Comment: @IagoBruno adicionei isso também. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal abri os 3 JSFiddle's e nenhum deles funcionou estou utilizando `Mozilla Firefox 27.0`

Comment: @PauloRoberto Atualizei todos os três. O problema é que o firefox não define o `e.x`, diferente do chrome. Usei `e.clientX`, que ambos os navegadores definem.

Comment: cara! ficou muito bom ! :) @GuilhermeBernal eu não sabia que tinha como fazer isso assim fácil achei que era extremamente mais complexo ! :)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal O seu exemplo foi o melhor que eu achei na internet, mas desde o dia em que você respondeu a pergunta eu venho tentando fazer com que ele também funcionasse com o scroll em outras posições =/. Se não fosse pedir muito =p queria que você adaptasse para que a barra de rolagem não afetasse a funcionalidade. Teria como?

Comment: @IagoBruno Acabei por reescrever tudo (a resposta acabou tendo bastante visibilidade). Veja agora :)

Comment: Agradeço, mas o do scroll deu errado =/

Comment: @Iago Pode dar mais detalhes do "não funcionou"? Qual teu navegador?

Comment: consegui consertar, você só trocou o ScrollLeft por Top e o Top por left. http://jsfiddle.net/qnN55/2/

Answer (score 5):

Peguei a resposta do **@Guilherme Bernal** (mais precisamente o exemplo de selecionar div's) e incrementei para que elas permaneçam selecionadas no evento mouseup.

Exemplo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caLsE/)

As mudanças foram:

- 1 - uma função nova para checar se um índice existe em um array (ele
  é alimentado conforme o usuário seleciona as div's);
- 2 - Pequenas implementações nos métodos já existentes de acordo com a
  resposta dele;
- 3 - A nova variável "var selecteds = [];".

---

```
window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    [...]
    selecteds = [];
};
```

---

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    [if->for]
            var rect = list[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            if (rect.bottom > y && rect.top < y+h &&
                rect.right > x && rect.left < x+w) {
                list[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                selecteds.push(list[i]);
            } else {
                list[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
            }
    [/if->/for]
};
```

---

```
window.onmouseup = function (e) {
    [...]
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        if(selecteds.length > 0){
            index = list.indexOf(i);
            if (index > -1) {
                array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        if(indexOf.call(selecteds, list[i])){return;}
        list[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }
};
```